# dropDups alternative in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, duplicates

I'm currently using MongoDB 3.2. After a period of time, I decided to create an index on `phone` field, which currently has many indistinct values. I haven't paid notice that since version 3.0, `dropDups`option is no longer viable. Hence, failed index ensuring prevents me from inserting any new document. Is there any solution besides deleting documents with duplicate `phone`?

Comment: Nope. Try this instead: `db.collectionName.aggregate([{ $group: { _id:{phone:'$phone'}, list: { $addToSet: '$_id' }}}, { $match: { 'list.1': { $exists: 1 } } }]).forEach(item => {
  const list = item.list.slice(1);
  db.collectionName.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: list } });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no alternative other than to delete the records with duplicate `phone`.

For background (though you have already seen this), from the [MongoDB 3.0 compatability docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#remove-dropdups-option):

> **Remove dropDups Option**
>
> dropDups option is no longer available for createIndex(), ensureIndex(), and createIndexes.